# Integer arithmetic in TeX

Tags: counters

After many years of being merely a regular TeX (LaTeX lately) I started reading little bit more recently. I wrote a small program (very naive) which is suppose to illustrate doing integer arithmetic in TeX.

```
\message{Please enter the first number:}
\read-1 to \first

The first entered number is \first

\count0=\first

\message{Please enter the second number:}
\read-1 to \second

\count1=\second

The second entered number is \second

\advance\count0 by \count1


Could you please compare the sum of number you have entered and
the number of the page :)
\bye
```

Is there a simple way to recover the content of register `\count0` on an arbitrary place on the page?

Comment: You find the total at the bottom of the page, as Plain TeX uses `\count0` for assigning the value to the page number. :)

Comment: I think you have not read my example carefully :)

Comment: Just a joke to advise you about being careful in not using `\count0` outside of a group. ;-)

Comment: I apologize for being a slow student :) I promise I will try to read comments more carefully and try to think before I replay :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to obtain `\count0`, use `\the\count0`. This will typeset the value of `\count0` wherever it is used.

[image]

```
\message{Please enter the first number:}
\read-1 to \first

The first entered number is \first

\count0=\first

\message{Please enter the second number:}
\read-1 to \second

\count1=\second

The second entered number is \second

\advance\count0 by \count1


Could you please compare the sum of number you have entered and
the number of the page :) \the\count0
\bye
```

Answer (score 11):

To complete the answer of Werner :

You can also use `\number`. If `\count213=1789` then `\the\count213`and `\number\count213` are equivalent, but if you can write `\number2012` it's not possible to write `\the2012` or `\the{2012}` .

If you want to learn something about integers with `TeX`, you can look at the sources of the `TeXBook`, for example Knuth writes this code :

> ```
> \newif\ifprime \newif\ifunknown
> \newcount\n \newcount\p \newcount\d \newcount\a
> \def\primes#1{2,~3% assume that #1 is at least 3
>   \n=#1 \advance\n by-2 % n more to go
>   \p=5 % odd primes starting with p
>   \loop\ifnum\n>0 \printifprime\advance\p by2 \repeat}
> \def\printp{, % we will invoke \printp if p is prime
>   \ifnum\n=1 and~\fi % this precedes the last value
>   \number\p \advance\n by -1 }
> \def\printifprime{\testprimality \ifprime\printp\fi}
> \def\testprimality{{\d=3 \global\primetrue
>   \loop\trialdivision \ifunknown\advance\d by2 \repeat}}
> \def\trialdivision{\a=\p \divide\a by\d
>   \ifnum\a>\d \unknowntrue\else\unknownfalse\fi
>   \multiply\a by\d
>   \ifnum\a=\p \global\primefalse\unknownfalse\fi}
> ```

In this code Knuth uses `\number\p`.

Comment: I have read the book first time twenty years ago but this is the first time I am reading the book (I have it next to me) with the mind set that TeX is general programming language. It is overwhelming with the breath of information. He has whole chapter with many exercises on arithmetics. We do not use TeX as a general purpose programming language but I am trying to discover those dark corners of TeX which I never use as a working Mathematician.