# Programmatically converting an integer into bits with graphical output

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, pgfmath

I just stumbled upon this interesting [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131689/how-to-automatically-draw-tree-diagram-of-prime-factorization-with-latex) about *"how to automatically draw tree diagrams of prime factorization with LaTeX"* and it rang a bell.

I 'd like to create a command that displays the conversion of an integer value into a bits string (which otherwise is a tedious operation to do "by hand") to use when preparing the exams of FOundation of Computer Science. This command needs 2 parameters, the integer to convert (213, for instance) and the desired number of bits for the result. The command should also be able to convert negative values by using [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The following pictures for values 137 (basic problem), -136 (negative problem) and -17 (problem requiring an 8 bits solution) should help you understand what kind of result I would like to get.

As a plus, I would like to introduce two variables to hold the min and max value allowed so that I can get the translation of a random integer value in [min, max] if I call the above command omitting the integer value. One could do the same with the number of desired bits and introduce a variable to hold an increment (4, for instance) so that it generates results with 4 bits and if a number requires 5 bits, for example, it automatically returns a solution that uses 8 bits. Not to mention that with an additional parameter one could convert to octal, hexadecimal, etc.

The problem is that I don't understand Tikz and I have no idea how to make LaTeX do maths! I read [this on integers in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/integer-arithmetic-in-tex) with interest, but I still miss too many things. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

---

[image: Conversion for 137]

---

[image: Conversion for -136]

---

[image: Conversion for -17]

Comment: I think this was a question here before... Here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96399/how-can-i-illustrate-decimal-to-binary-conversion Please use that and narrow down the focus of this question. Right now it's a *do-it-for-me* question

Comment: (I would definitely like to help if only I was not under pressure from urgent deadlines. I am sure nice proposals will appear here, I will have time 10 days from now). For just plain conversion to binary you have package [binhex](http://ctan.org/pkg/binhex), and for integers exceeding TeX limits there is [xintbinhex](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint)

Comment: Hi @jfbu and thanks for your kind reply! I just had a look to `binhex` and `xint`, much appreciated! Does the second provides statements for loops and similar? I'll try to go through the docs with more details... otherwise I'll write a Java program that generates the LaTeX code that uses `binhex` and I'll simply forget about `Tikz`. Cheers!

Comment: Another related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107637/1952 It doesn't solve the `programmatically` part of your question but several solutions to display repeated divisions.

Comment: Hi @Ignasi thanks for reporting this question! The content is very interesting... I hope to be able to read through it (anytime I see Tikz, my mind fails)... anyway if I put together something meaningful, I'll post it here as an answer to my question.

Comment: `xint` provides means for expandable loops, using its `\xintApplyUnbraced\macro\list` syntax, where `\macro` is a one parameter macro, and `\list` a sequence of tokens or braced groups. For example if `\list` expands to `{1}{2}{3}` then `\macro` is executed for its argument being `1`, `2`, `3`. The user is supposed to know how to  expandably first create `{1}{2}...{N}` for an arbitrary `N` if this is what is needed for `\list`, see the `etex` manual for a way to do that (next release of `xint` will presumably add such a facility).